# Unique identifier for all products sold in the US

Tags: e-commerce

I'm going to develop a website for price comparison of products sold in the US. Price information is edited by merchants, buyers and visitors (people who didn't buy). I wonder what kind identifier can I use to identify each product? This identifier should be

- unique to each version of each product
- easy to obtain, giving that product at hand or only the name, images (and description, etc.) of that product showing at an online store.

Is it UPC a good choice? Not sure if this kind of questions should be asked at SO. If not, feel free to move this question or vote for close.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find that a combination of UPC and EAN will be required to cover all product types including non-US products.

Refer to [UPC and EAN Bar Code Page](http://www.adams1.com/upccode.html)

Comment: But most online stores do not include UPC or EAN in their product description pages. Any quick way to search UPC or EAN by product name and manufacturer?